# Group rows within a data.frame based on specific sequence of grouping numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, rows, seq

Here an example of my data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'colA
1
1
1
0
1
1
0
0
0
1', header = TRUE)
```

I need to group `colA` rows based on specific grouping numbers, such as 3, 2, 2, 3 and assign to them a number from 1900 to 1903.

Desired output:

```
 colA  colB
    1   1900
    1   1900
    1   1900
    0   1901
    1   1901
    1   1902
    0   1902
    0   1903
    0   1903
    1   1903
```

The 4 grouping numbers mean: 1st group = first 3 rows, 2nd group = subsequent 2 rows, 3rd group = subsequent 2 rows and 4th group = subsequent 3 rows.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `rep`

```
df$colB <- rep(1900:1903, c(3, 2, 2, 3))
df$colB
#[1] 1900 1900 1900 1901 1901 1902 1902 1903 1903 1903
```

Comment: yep..good. thank you. let me apply it to my real data and will mark as best answer ;_0